# How to clone part of DOM and put it inside a div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

$("id").clone()

then put the jQuery object into a div#target

how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#id').clone().attr('id', 'foo').appendTo('#target') 
// the .attr to prevent duplicate ids.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id').clone().appendTo('div#target');
```